# Convert String to NSDate but still not accessing dateByAddingTimeInterval method

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdate

```
   @IBAction func onDateChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    
   // dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    
    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    
    let timeinterval = NSTimeInterval.abs(17 * 60) //time in seconds
    let newDate = strDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-timeinterval)
    // ERROR =- on the above line I get an error saying that type String does not have a method called dateByAddingTimeInterval, however I made the string a NSDate value in the variable newDate.

    
    print("\(strDate) is the date on the datePicker @")
}
```

As you can see I clearly converted the string value of the date picker into an NSDate in line 7, but it still is not letting me use the `dateByAddingTimeInterval` method because it still thinks it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did the opposite of what you thought you were doing. `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)` converts a `NSDate` to a `String`. If this was your intention, you should add your time interval to the date before converting it to a `String`. Like so.

```
let timeinterval = NSTimeInterval.abs(17 * 60) //time in seconds
let newDate = datePicker.date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-timeinterval)
let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate)
print("\(strDate) is the date on the datePicker @")
```